# Activate Trigger from Foreign Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, triggers

WPF newbie here so excuse the simple question.  How do I cause a trigger to fire on a UserControl from a control outside of that UserControl?  Here's what I want to do...

I have a UserControl with a trigger set to display a background color change on itself when IsMouseOver is True.  If I mouse over the UserControl, the trigger fires as I expect.  What I'd like to do is to create a window that contains the UserControl and a button, and when the user mouses over the button, fire the UserControl's trigger.  Something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.SimpleUCTry1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.SimpleUCTry1"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <local:Simple />
    <Button Content="Foo" />
</StackPanel>
```

So if the user mouses over the "Foo" button, the "Simple" UserControl's trigger would fire.

Is this possible?

Thank you,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your control is "external" to the button, you cannot use property triggers or data triggers to flip the background. What you need is an EventTrigger on Window level.

Start a keyframe or discrete color animation with 0 duration on MouseEnter and remove the mentioned storyboard on MouseLeave:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="button">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Change_Control_Background_Start" 
            Storyboard="{StaticResource Change_Control_Background}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="button">
        <RemoveStoryboard 
            BeginStoryboardName="Change_Control_Background_Start"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Would it be also possible to accomplish this with an EventSetter or a RoutedUICommand perhaps?

Comment: It is possible to do with EventSetter, but would require a code-behind handler (in that case, you can even handle mouse events directly by the button). 
As for RoutedUICommand, it is not a good match. Command is something that user does deliberately, and hovering does not fall into this category.

Answer (score 1):

Sergey's answer is the way to do it, in case you need something that can't be done with EventTrigger you can always wrap your controls in a DataTemplate and use ContentPresenter to show it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.SimpleUCTry1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.SimpleUCTry1"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:Simple Name="Ctrl1" />
                    <Button Name="Ctrl2" Content="Foo" />
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Ctrl2" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Ctrl1" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is a nice way to do it - since Andy already has the UserControl. Just add the button mentioned to it (by definition it is tied to it visually already), and use the mentioned ContentPresenter trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yet one more way to do it (requires some code behind but is probably the cleanest}

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:Simple Background="{Binding ElementName=bnFoo, 
                  Path=IsMouseOver, 
                  Converter={StaticResource boolToBackgroundConv}}"/>
    <Button Name="bnFoo" Content="Foo" />
</StackPanel>
```